# Unrecognized C macro

Tags: c, macros, multiline

I've come across a macro defined in a C header file that I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding.

```
#if BAR
  #define FOO(s,err) \
          ((SOMEPOINTER)(s))->VALID != SOMEVARIABLE \
        ? (err) \
        :
#else
  #define FOO(s,err)
```

and that's it. I understand what's going on with the `if`/`else`, but I'm not sure what the first macro definition of `FOO` is doing. There's obviously a ternary operation going on, but I'm curious about the `->` as I can't find references to it online. I'm also curious about the fact that there don't seem to be any return values here. What's the point of doing a comparison if you're not returning anything regardless of the outcome? To be honest, the "\" guys in there are freaking me out a bit too.

Comment: Preprocessor macros do not return values at all, and the `->` operator lets you access `struct` fieslds for `struct` poitners.

Comment: Is there something missing after that `:` ?? Because as written it looks like a screwed up ternary operator.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your queries,

1. The `->` is a structure pointer dereference operator, used to refer a member variable of a pointer to structure type.
2. The `\` is used to write multi-line MACROS. In reference to `C11` standard, chapter §6.10.3,

> The parameters are specified by the optional list of identifiers, whose scope extends from their declaration in the identifier list **until the new-line** character that terminates the `#define` preprocessing directive.

So, to span a definition of a MACRO over multiple line, you need to use the `\`.

3. `#define` MACROs don't *return* any value. It's considered as a *textual replacement* in the preprocessing stage.

Answer (score 4):

```
if the name 'BAR' is defined to the pre processor of the compiler
then
    define a macro 'FOO( s, err )'
    with the replacement text:
        "((SOMEPOINTER)(s))->VALID != SOMEVARIABLE ? (err) :"
        which is a ternary operator with a missing final parameter
        (so it would use what ever statement follows the macro invocation

else, when the name 'BAR' is not known to the pre processor of the compiler
then
    define the macro 'FOO( s, err )' as 'nothing
    (so what ever statement follows the macro invocation will always be executed, 
    rather than conditionally executed (as it would be above)
```

Comment: so, if we assume that 'SOMEPOINTER' is a struct pointer, 's' is a handle to an object that matches the struct and 'SOMEVARIABLE' holds a value to check against, this will go to "err" if the VALID portion of 's' doesn't match 'SOMEVARIABLE', and go to the next statement if it does?

Comment: well, (err) is what ever the invoker of the macro has written.   That part is regular C ternary statement.   The only real trick is if 'BAR' is not previously defined.  suggest looking at the answer by @Mints97

Answer (score 2):

To answer your **question about the ternary**, it's either an example of a mistype (forgetting to finish typing the code) or someone trying to make his own (weird and counterintuitive) syntaxis. The macro could be used like this:

```
FOO(someVar, doThisIfSomeVarIsBad) doThisIfSomeVarIsGood(stuff);
```

Where `someVar` is a pointer (pointer-to-struct or pointer-to-struct cast to a different pointer type), `doThisIfSomeVarIsBad` is a function pointer to an error-showing function, and `doThisIfSomeVarIsGood(stuff)` is any statement.

This is quite generic (as your example is), but I hope you get the idea.

This is a funny but still weird way to do error handling. But well, it's not really that bad, I've seen worse preprocessor abuse...

To answer **your other questions**:

`((SOMEPOINTER)(s))->VALID` means that you're casting `s` to a pointer-to-struct type and accessing its member (`->` means accessing a `struct` member through a pointer-to-struct).

`\`, appearing before a newline, "escapes" the newline. That is needed because `#define`-s should be (formally) one-liners, so if you're splitting a macro across lines, you have to make the compiler think it's still one line.

And yeah, function-like macros are different from inline functions, they don't *return* anything. They are simple text-replacement tools, they just replace some code with some different code.

Comment: I was hoping that it wasn't something like that.

Comment: @PeterM: hah, me too, but I think it's obvious that this macro was to be used that way. It can't work in anything else, IMHO

Comment: and to top it all off, this code is buried at the end of a series of macros pointing to other macros... talk about diving in at the deep end